# Pegar HTML de várias DIVs com o mesmo ID

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para obter conteúdo de uma pagina da WEB onde tenho várias DIVs com os mesmo IDs. Uma parece a outra, a `div 1`, é como se fosse um Titulo, já a `Div 2` como se fosse o conteúdo...

Mas o problema que a `div 2` pode ter diversas, uma debaixo da outra, antes de vir a proxima `div 1`.

Como eu faço para pegar essas divs com esses IDs?

Após eu pegar essa `Div 2`, eu tenho que veridicar se o primeiro elemento dentro dela possuí a class `DIV_3`, caso ela tenha esse elemento, eu tenho que pular todas as `divs 2` e ir direto para a próxima `div 1`...

Eu tenho um objeto, com todo o conteúdo HTML do site:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2">
   <div class="3"></div>
   <div class="10"></div>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <div class="10"></div>
    <div class="10"></div>
    <div class="10"></div>
</div>
<div id="1"></div><!--Próxima DIV 1-->
```

Entende, primeiro preciso separar todas as divis de um objeto com os `ID 1 e 2`:

Depois de separar eles teriam um HTML semelhante ao de cima ( Mas com muito mais `DIV 1 e Div 2`), daí eu tenho que fazer uma verificação, caso a primeira `DIV 2`, tenha dentro dela uma class `DIV 3`, eu tenho que pular diretamente para a próxima `DIV 1`...

Eu tentei com find, mas não obtive sucesso, primeiro que o find pega o que tem dentro, e primeiro eu preciso separar de todo o objeto, as `DIVs 1  e DIVs 2`...

Se alguém puder dar uma força... ATT

Answer (score 7):

Em HTML os `id` têm de ser unicos. É uma das regras da linguagem.

Repara ainda que o método nativo para selecionar um elemento por `id` é getElementById, no singular e vai retornar 1 elemento, o primeiro que encontrar, independentemente de quantos elementos tenhas na página com o ID igual. O jQuery igual, retorna somente o primeiro que encontrar.

Claro que podes fazer aldrabice e usar:

```
var id = {}
$('body > div').each(function(){
    if (id[this]) id[this].push(this);
    else id[this.id] = [this]; 
});
```

e depois iterar os elementos desse objeto qua agrupa elementos por `id`. Sinceramente só faz isso quem não sabe o que está a fazer.

### A solução:

Muda no HTML esses `id` para `class`. O teu HTML poderia ficar assim:

```
<div class="title"></div>
<div class="content">
   <div class="3"></div>
   <div class="10"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="10"></div>
    <div class="10"></div>
    <div class="10"></div>
</div>
```

e depois o que precisas fazer com JavaScript/jQuery é:

para capturar os elementos `title`

```
$('.title')
```

para capturar os elementos content que têm uma `div` com classe `3`:

```
$('.title > .3').map(function(){ return $(this).parent(); });
```

#### Nota:

Como [o @DanielOmine referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57582/pegar-html-de-v%c3%a1rias-divs-com-o-mesmo-id/57599#comment118734_57599), e bem, convém usar classes que começam por letras. Apesar de ser aceite no HTML5 e CSS3 classes que começam por digitos, ainda há muita gente com browsers antigos.

Comment: editei os atributos "class" pois é recomendável não usar somente números ou iniciar com números. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @DanielOmine obrigado pela intenção, mas na verdade as classes podem começar com numeros. Essa discussão foi mais acesa ainda com `id`, mas até aí com HTML5 o problema foi resolvido e pode usar-se numeros livremente.

Comment: Estamos ainda longe de ter o HTML4 e CSS2 como obsoletos.

Comment: obrigado sergio, quando chegar em casa vou testar...  Em relação  ao ID com números, foi paracdar o exemplo...  já a questão das divs com o mesmo id, isso ocorre pois é  uma página web, onde tenho que pegar o conteúdo... não fui eu quem desenvolveu...

Comment: @DanielOmine verdade.

Comment: @abcd se não podes mudar a outra página (o que é preocupante) testa a solução "aldrabice" que sugerí. Ela parte do principio que essas `div` são descendentes diretas do `body` etc. Se precisares de ajuda a implementar faz um jsFiddle com o HTML original com que tens de trabalhar para eu ver.

Comment: @Sergio Consegui realizar o que deseja usando o `find()` e `each`, como ele retorna o que tem dentro da div que selecionava, eu pegar o ID `$(this).attr('id')` e alterava a nova class que criava...  Na questão do filho, eu fiz uma validação, se existisse a class 3, crio uma variável recebendo `TRUE`, dai ela só vai receber false quando chegar um novo `class title`... ATT

Comment: @abcd fico contente que tenhas resolvido o problema. Se quiseres podes marcar como aceite uma das respostas ou então coloca uma resposta tua se fôr diferente do que sugerimos.

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa que estou vendo é que você está usando `IDs` iguais. A ideia seria o uso de **classes** e não de `IDs`, pois cada `ID` é único na página.

No seu código, você tem algo como o abaixo, e os comentários mostram o que ocorre na página.

```
Div I1 { //Perdeu o ID!
  Div I2 { //Perdeu o ID!
    Div C3
    Div C10
  }
  Div I2 {
    Div C10
    Div C10
    Div C10
  }
}
Div I1 { }
```

IX = ID X

CX = Class X

Por exemplo, o CSS abaixo:

```
.1 /*atenção ao espaçamento!*/ #ident { //regras
}
```

Faz com que ele pegue o elemento com `ID` **ident** que esteja dentro de um elemento com a classe **1** e aplique as regras de CC determinadas no arquivo/tag...