# Como pegar valores contidos em uma tabela?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um carrinho de compras onde traz as seguintes informações:

```
<tr class="rem1">
   <td class="invert">R$<span id="produto">270,00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="rem2">
   <td class="invert">R$<span id="produto">280,00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="rem3">
   <td class="invert">R$<span id="produto">290,00</span></td>
</tr>
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar no click o valor desses produtos? 
Tentei assim:

```
$('.value-plus').on('click', function() {
            valor = document.getElementById("produto").innerHTML;
            trocar = valor.replace(",", ".");
            alert(trocar);
}
```

Mas quando clico, traz somente do primeiro produto (200,00).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo `id` no html deve ser unico, por isso isso ele apenas traz o primeiro.

Você poderia selecionar seus itens e a partir dessa seleção. você poderia percorrer com o método `$.each(function(index, item){})` do jQuery.

Ficaria dessa forma:

```js
$('.value-plus').on('click', function(){

  var lista = $('.invert > span');
  
  $.each(lista, function(index,item){
  
    valor = $(item).text();
    trocar = valor.replace(",",".");
    alert(trocar);
  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="rem1">
<td class="invert">R$<span id="produto">270,00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="rem2">
<td class="invert">R$<span id="produto">280,00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="rem3">
<td class="invert">R$<span id="produto">290,00</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="myButton" class="value-plus">Pegar Valores</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não é ideal você colocar um mesmo ID para varios elementos, como o @Sergio explica nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57582/pegar-html-de-v%C3%A1rias-divs-com-o-mesmo-id).

Modifiquei o seu código e peguei os valores usando o [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), ficaria assim:

```js
$('.value-plus').on('click', function() {
    var valores = document.querySelectorAll("table tr td span");
    for (i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
        console.log(valores[i].innerHTML);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr class="rem1">
      <td class="invert">R$<span>270,00</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="rem2">
      <td class="invert">R$<span>280,00</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="rem3">
      <td class="invert">R$<span>290,00</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<button class='value-plus'>Pegar Valores</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` é um atributo que não pode ser repetido, além de não ser semântico, `document.getElementById` sempre irá retornar apenas um elemento. Sugiro alterar para outro seletor qualquer (como `class` por exemplo):

```js
$('.value-plus').on('click', function() {
  let elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("produto");
  let valores = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    valores.push(elementos[i].innerHTML.replace(",", "."));
  };
  console.log(valores);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="rem1">
  <td class="invert">R$<span class="produto" id="produto">270,00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="rem2">
  <td class="invert">R$<span class="produto" id="produto">280,00</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="rem3">
  <td class="invert">R$<span class="produto" id="produto">290,00</span></td>
</tr>
<button class="value-plus">Checar</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos. Todas as soluções colocadas aqui funcionaram.

Answer (score 0):

Sei que o tópico é antigo, mas como eu passe RAIVA DEMAIS para encontrar uma resposta para uma pergunta tão simples (com tantos pseudo-sábios que não falam o óbvio - parece que ganha para ficar escondendo o jogo), criei a conta apenas para colocar esse trecho de código:

```
exibir() {
        $(document).on('click', '#tbody-detalhe-ambiente td', function(){
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
            var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // pega valor da 1ª td
            var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // pega valor da 2ª td
            var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // pega valor da 3ª td... por aí vai
            var data = col1 + "\n" + col2 + "\n" + col3;
            alert(data);
        });
    }
```

```html
<table id="detalhe-ambiente">

    <thead class="thead-dark text-center" style="font-size: smaller;">
        <tr>
            <th style="padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;">ID</th>
            <th style="padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;">AMBIENTE</th>
            <th style="padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;">MEDIÇÃO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tbody-detalhe-ambiente">
      <tr onclick="exibir()">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>AAAA</td>
          <td>BBBB</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).