# While com PHP e Datapicker

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho uma página que é alimentado com informações do Banco de Dados Mysql. Esta página também contém um Input Text com calendário dataPicker. O problema é que apenas a primeira linha do looping funciona com DataPicker, as demais não.

## Formulario:

```
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($xxx)){ 

     <input  name="protocolo" id="protocolo" type="text" 
     placeholder="00/00/0000" 
     style="width:100px;font-size: 13px" class="form-control input-md">
```

## DataPicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#protocolo").datepicker({
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        prevText: 'Anterior'
    });
});
</script>
     } ?>
```

Ambos estão dentro do While, testei colocando o DataPicker fora do white, porem o problema permanece, apenas a primeira linha do While abre o calendário, as demais não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O atributo `ID` deve ser único. Quando você tem mais de dois elementos com o mesmo atributo `ID`. O *JavaScript* irá considerar apenas o primeiro.

Ao invés de utilizar `ID`, utilize outros atributos como `class`, `data-*` etc.

Ex:

```
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($xxx)){ 
    <input name="protocolo[]" type="text" 
            placeholder="00/00/0000" 
            style="width:100px;font-size: 13px" class="form-control protocolo input-md"/>
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".protocolo").datepicker({
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        prevText: 'Anterior'
    });
});
</script>
```

---

O mesmo vale para o atributo `name`. Quando você enviar o formulário, apenas um dos valores serão enviados os repetidos serão descartados, por isso você deve usar `name="protocolo[]"`

Comment: neste caso eu acrescento apenas o [] no ID do input id="protocolo[]" e altero o # pelo . no datapicker? Pois, fiz esta alteração e o datapicker parou de responder, agora nem a primeira linha sobe o calendario.

Comment: @user54154 Não! O `[]` só pode ser usado no atributo `name`. Você deve adicionar a classe `protocolo` *no input*  (Ex: `class="protocolo form-control..."`) e no javascript utilizar `$(".protocolo")`. Se possível copie e cole o código que postei na resposta e verifique.

Comment: Boaaa, era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda e aprendi mais uma :)

Comment: sabe me dizer porque ele só alimenta o primeiro Input com data? Se eu alimentar qualquer input que não seja o primeiro, ele vai mesmo assim, adiciona a data no primeiro Input.

Comment: Ele só alimenta o primeiro (quando está com o ID) pois é uma regra do HTML. Aqui há uma resposta mais completa sobre esse "problema": https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57582/pegar-html-de-v%C3%A1rias-divs-com-o-mesmo-id